# GCC called from GHC cannot find generated file

Tags: haskell, gcc, ghc, ffi

I have a project which uses the FFI to interact with some C++ code. I upgraded GHC to 7.10.3 and now the project doesn't compile anymore.

I have to use a quite old gcc (3.3.6) and it is called with this line:

```
ghc ${DEFINES}  ${INCLUDES} ${LIBDIRS} -pgmc /opt/gcc-3.3.6/bin/gcc MISCconfigTest.hs csrc/MISCconfig_c.cpp ${LIBRARIES}
```

Since the ghc upgrade, the following error is raised:

```
gcc: @/tmp/ghc19542_0/ghc_2.rsp: No such file or directory
```

Does anybody have an idea what's wrong?

**EDIT:**

This is the output of ghc -v3:

```
Hsc static flags: 
Created temporary directory: /tmp/ghc29748_0
*** C Compiler:
/opt/gcc-3.3.6/bin/gcc -D__OMNIORB4__ -D__x86__ -D__linux__ '-D__OSVERSION__=2' -DS2K_NAMESPACE -DUSE_NESTED_TEMPLATES -DIL_STD -D_REENTRANT -DS2K_LINUX -DUSE_STD_ALLOCATORS -DREDEFINE_STRING -DTCL_THREADS -x 'c++' csrc/MISCconfig_c.cpp -o /tmp/ghc29748_0/ghc_1.s -S '-D__GLASGOW_HASKELL__=710' -include /home/oswald/ghcs/ghc-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3/include/ghcversion.h -I/development/GECCOS_MUM/RELEASE3.1_W-03/core-stl-rep/include -I/development/GECCOS_MUM/RELEASE3.1_W-03/core-utilities-rep/include -I/development/GECCOS_MUM/RELEASE3.1_W-03/core-comm-rep/include -I/development/GECCOS_MUM/RELEASE3.1_W-03/model-cpd-rep/include -I/opt/omniORB-4.1.0/include/omniORB4 -I/opt/omniORB-4.1.0/include -I/development/GECCOS_MUM/RELEASE3.1_W-03/_generated -I/development/GECCOS_MUM/RELEASE3.1_W-03/../COTS/core-build-rep/include -I/home/oswald/ghcs/ghc-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3/base_HQfYBxpPvuw8OunzQu6JGM/include -I/home/oswald/ghcs/ghc-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3/integ_2aU3IZNMF9a7mQ0OzsZ0dS/include -I/home/oswald/ghcs/ghc-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3/include
gcc: @/tmp/ghc29748_0/ghc_2.rsp: No such file or directory
gcc: no input files
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting: /tmp/ghc29748_0/ghc_2.rsp /tmp/ghc29748_0/ghc_1.s
Warning: deleting non-existent /tmp/ghc29748_0/ghc_1.s
*** Deleting temp dirs:
Deleting: /tmp/ghc29748_0
make: *** [MISCconfig] Error 1
```

I don't know the structure of the intermediate files that ghc generates, but it looks like that gcc gets a temporary .s file and the .rsp file is referenced inside?

Comment: What does `ghc -v3` give you? In particular, you'll want to find what exact gcc command it is calling.

Comment: See output in the edit above.

Comment: Could this just be an issue with permissions? Does the file/folder exist and can you access it? If you run with `-keep-tmp-files` it won't delete the temp files at  the end.

Comment: I checked, the directory is there and there is a file ghc_1.rsp in there. The permissions are ok. I had a look in the file and it's just the command line options. What makes me suspicious is the @-character at the line: `gcc: @/tmp/ghc9716_0/ghc_1.rsp: No such file or directory`. The temp files are created in `/tmp/ghc9716_0/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New `ghc`s use [response files](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8596) to work around windows limitations on path length. The at sign syntax is part of [how response files work](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Response_Files). However it appears (see the second link) that response file support was added to `gcc` subsequent to the old version of gcc you use. So while that pins down the source of the problem, I'm afraid no particularly great answer springs to mind on how to address it :-/.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that clears it up. Unfortunately because of of a linking dependency I have to use the old gcc version (the ABI has changed between 3.3 and 3.4), so I think I have to stay with an older ghc as well for a while.